# cv2.rectangle() draws improper rectangle on image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, drawing

The idea is simple: user clicks on the image at some point P(x,y) then the app takes this coordinate which determine center of a square. The square then should appear around P(x,y). But instead of it I get rectangle with improper shape.
My code below.

Create event of clicking:
`window.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)`
(https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/event_handling.html)

Then:

```
frameSize = 64
ix, iy = 0, 0
def onclick(event):
    global ix, iy

# take the coordinates of user`s click
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    print (f'Center:\tx = {ix}, y = {iy} frameSize = {frameSize}')
   

#print coordinates
    print ("----------------------")
    left_TOP_x = int(ix - frameSize/2)
    left_TOP_y = int(iy - frameSize/2)
    right_BOTTOM_x = int(ix + frameSize/2)
    right_BOTTOM_y = int(iy + frameSize/2)
    print (f'to int\t left_TOP_x = {left_TOP_x}, left_TOP_y = {left_TOP_y}')
    print (f'to int\t right_BOTTOM_x = {right_BOTTOM_x}, right_BOTTOM_y = {right_BOTTOM_y}')
    print ("----------------------\n")

#draw the square
    cv2.rectangle(img, (left_TOP_x,left_TOP_y,right_BOTTOM_x, right_BOTTOM_y ), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness= 2)
    window.ax.imshow(img)
    window.canvas.draw()
```

I make first click and recieve this:

(image size is 254x199)
 [improper rectangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFmMm.jpg)

But the coordinates always are fine!

```
Center: x = 131.67556141774892, y = 111.16829004329006 frameSize = 64
----------------------
to int   left_TOP_x = 99, left_TOP_y = 79
to int   right_BOTTOM_x = 163, right_BOTTOM_y = 143
----------------------
```

I made GUI via QtDesigner (maybe it is important)

```
self.plotWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.plotWidget)
       
        self.plotWidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.plotWidget.setObjectName("plotWidget")
        self.plotLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.plotWidget)
        self.plotLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)  
        self.plotLayout.setObjectName("plotLayout")
```

I've tryed to crop the image with this coords. I [get image that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vInxB.png)

```
 crop_img = img[left_TOP_y:right_BOTTOM_y, left_TOP_x:right_BOTTOM_x]
    crop_img = cv2.cvtColor(crop_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   
    cv2.imshow("imagggge", crop_img)
    test_image(crop_img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But I have not solved the problem of drawing square yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`cv2.rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9) has two forms:

```
cv.rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, color, ...)
cv.rectangle(img, rec, color, ...)
```

The first form takes the top left and the bottom right corners as parameters describing the rectangle. The second form takes a (C++ type) `cv::Rect` as parameter describing the rectangle. The `Rect` is derived as `(x, y, width, height)`, with `(x, y)` corresponding to `pt1` in the first form.

So your square drawing line should be either

```
cv2.rectangle(img, (left_TOP_x, left_TOP_y, frameSize, frameSize), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness= 2)
```

or

```
cv2.rectangle(img, (left_TOP_x, left_TOP_y), (right_BOTTOM_x, right_BOTTOM_y), color=(255, 0, 0), thickness= 2)
```